# Polymer 2.0 version issue

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to a make an element that uploads an image to the server. I'm using [this component](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/bluewatertracks/bwt-uploader).

The problem is that if I use the above element with polymer 1.0, then it works like a charm but if I use it with Polymer 2.0 then some of its features like progress-bar and delete button don't work.

I'm using Bower to install this element and while installing this element(in polymer 2.0) I get many different choices like:

[image]

Which one should I choose?

Comment: element is not suitable for polymer 2.0 you have to wait for owner to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to Polymer 2.0 requires [some steps](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade). Based on the page of the element it targets Polymer 1.4 and is not [hybrid](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/hybrid-elements) yet. It means you cannot use it with Polymer 2.0 yet and need to wait for authors to upgrade it to hybrid element supported by both Polymer 1.9 and 2.0.